# Bijection $h:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, borel-measures

I would like to find a referenceable source of the following cool technique to get an explicit bijection $h:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ that is measurable and has measurable inverse:

**Cool technique developed in [?]:** Write $x \in [0,1)$ in its unique binary expansion that does not contain an infinite tail of 1s and then parse that expansion by:
$$x = 0.w_1w_2w_3...$$
where $w_i \in \{0, 10, 110, 1110, ...\}$. Then define $h:[0,1)\rightarrow[0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ by defining each component function $h_i(x)$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ as:
$$ h_i(x) = 0.w_{\phi(i,1)}w_{\phi(i,2)}w_{\phi(i,3)}...$$
where $\phi:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is any bijection. Clearly the given expansion for each $h_i(x)$ does not contain an infinite tail of 1s since each word $w_i$ ends with 0.

**Reference note**: I remember reading about this on either mathoverflow or stackexchange, which is how I know about the technique, but I cannot find the link again! Chapter 13 in Dudley's book *Real Analysis and Probability* treats this topic using single-bit binary expansions rather than the variable-bit expansion in the above technique.  Durrett's book and Kallenberg's book both cite Dudley. So these three references have the main result on existence of a bijection, but do not have the explicit bijection given above.

Comment: Related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_system.

Comment: @copper.hat : How so?

Comment: A better link: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269378/27978